# how does html link parser preprocessor works in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, preprocessor

I want to know about the working of HTML links parser preprocessor that how does it work how to retrieve all links and all other elements that are present in the HTML response. As far as I have checked on each blog it is written that .* will extract all links but what about other elements what if I don't want links and I want to test with other elements like I want to fetch image source or I want to play with drop down or radio button available in response . How can I extract those?
Is there going to be any other regex for that or the same one .*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser)

> This modifier parses HTML response from the server and extracts **links and forms**

so there are 2 main use cases for the HTML link parser:

- [site links crawling (spidering)](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-spider-site-jmeter-tutorial)
- [submitting random data into a form](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#poll_example)

In both cases you need to provide a [Perl-5 Compatible Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) in order to limit crawling to current domain or narrow down options selection.

---

If you need to fetch image(s) source(s) the best option would be using [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) configured like:

- Selector: `img`
- Attribute: `src`

[image: JMeter CSS JQuery Extractor]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your valuable reply